# Reading XML table within table

Tags: c#, xml, nested-lists

I have the following XML which I believe is completely valid:

```
<Controls>
  <ComboBox>
    <ControlName>cbInputType</ControlName>
    <ControlText>Input Type</ControlText>
    <EnumDefault>2</EnumDefault>
    <EnumList value="0">
      <EnumText>Type A</EnumText>
      <EnumLegend>TA</EnumLegend>
    </EnumList>
    <EnumList value="1">
      <EnumText>Type B</EnumText>
      <EnumLegend>TB</EnumLegend>
    </EnumList>
    <EnumList value="2">
      <EnumText>Type C</EnumText>
      <EnumLegend>TC</EnumLegend>
    </EnumList>
  </ComboBox>
  <ComboBox>
    <ControlName>cbDecimalPlace</ControlName>
    <ControlText>Decimal Place</ControlText>
    <EnumDefault>1</EnumDefault>
    <EnumList value="0">
      <EnumText>0dp (1234)</EnumText>
      <EnumLegend>0000</EnumLegend>
    </EnumList>
    <EnumList value="1">
      <EnumText>1dp (123.4)</EnumText>
      <EnumLegend>000.0</EnumLegend>
    </EnumList>
  </ComboBox>
</Controls>
```

The idea is that it specifies what is contained in two "ComboBox" controls. Using the EnumList definition in the XML is should populate the first ComboBox with the 3 items defined (Type A, Type B & Type C) and the second ComboBox with 2 items (0dp & 1dp).
I am using the ReadXml method to read the XML into a dataset.

Now for the question:
I can access the tables within the dataset however if I access the ComboBox table, which correctly contains the initial data from each, there is no EnumList within that. I can also access the table EnumList, but this contains all the enums in the file so they do not appear to be tied to specific ComboBox instances.

Part of the problem might be I am just not reading the data correctly. I am basically doing:

```
DataSet ds = ReadXML("myxmltable.xml");
DataTable dt = ds.Tables["ComboBox"];
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

This fills my DGV with only the first 3 items from each ComboBox definition, not the enumList. And trying to debug into the dataset object i cannot see any information about the EnumLists.

If i change the second line of code in the above example to:

```
DataTable dt = ds.Tables["EnumList"];
```

I get all the enumlists in the whole file so i cannot see which combobox they are related to.

I cannot believe that the ReadXML function flattens the structure as I have defined it, as this would defeat the point of XML, so I guess I must be using it wrong??

Any ideas?

Comment: You should show the code you have tried and tell exactly what it fails to do. It would really help answering your question.

Comment: Update the question with your code. Helps us a lot.

Comment: I have added the last 4 paragraphs to explain how i am reading it.

Comment: `DataSet` and `DataTable` are suitable for database-like data structures, so only 2 level structure makes sense. Use `XDocument` or `XmlReader` instead.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the input. Thanks Bartosz i ended up using XDocument and actually its pretty easy and its working great now.